# how to add container to item in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to put a container for my tables

```
<div class="single-post-content">
    <div class="responsive-tables">
        <table></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

To do this I wrote the following code:

```
$('.single-post-content').find('table').before('<div class="responsive-tables">');
$('.single-post-content').find('table').after('</div>');
```

But this is how it is created:

```
<div class="single-post-content">
    <div class="responsive-tables"></div>
    <table></table>
</div>
```

please guide me.

Comment: You can youse jquery 'wrap' function  Example: "$( "table" ).wrap( wrap element );"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the jQuery function .wrap

```
$('.single-post-content').find('table').wrap('<div class="responsive-tables"></div>');
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/